# between XLink, XPointer and XInclude

Tags: xml, xpath

What is the difference between `XLink`, `XPointer` and `XInclude`?

It's so confusing. Could somebody please explain the difference?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

XLink and XPointer are very similar in the sense they provide a way to reference other elements, however the major difference (besides the syntax) is that:

- with XLink you can reference *other or the same* xml documents
- with XPointer you can reference portions of the *same* xml document only

XInclude instead is to combine different xml documents into one.
It's important to note that the inclusion happens straight after parsing and before any other processing. The classic example is to imagine a book composed by several chapters and each chapter is a separate xml document

**Long answer:**

- https://www.w3.org/TR/xlink11/
- https://www.w3.org/TR/xptr/
- http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xlink.asp
- https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/